# How to display a Jasper Report inside a HTML page

Tags: java, html, spring, jasper-reports, thymeleaf

So, I already have the report made, but the problem is that I'm using GetMapping to display, and it opens on another page alone, but I need it to open on a div, a table, a card, or even a modal. It just can't change from the previous page.

I have no idea how to open it with out redirecting the page. Any suggestion is appreciated

Method on the controller

```
@GetMapping("/seguro")
    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JRException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        jasperPrint = seguroReportService.generatePromissoria(1L);
        HtmlExporter htmlExporter = new HtmlExporter(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
        htmlExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        htmlExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(response.getWriter()));
        htmlExporter.exportReport();
    }
```

Method to get the report file

```
public JasperPrint generatePromissoria(Long id) throws SQLException, JRException, IOException {
        Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

        String path = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/reports/SeguroReport.jrxml").getURI().getPath();

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
        // Parameters for report
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("titulo", "Relatório de Seguros");
        parameters.put("ID", id);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);

        return print;
    }
```

[page where is supposed to open the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YQ65.png)

[Report opening in another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzGtG.png)

Comment: What are you using on the web side? jQuery, Angular, trying to put in an iFrame, etc?  Based on that there are different methods.

Comment: @kendavidson I'm new to this, don't know if answer your question, but i'm using spring and thymeleaf. I'm gonna take a look the iframe, seems interesting.

Comment: Make sure you write up what you did to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem using the Iframe, but instead of passing the HTML on the src="", I made a onClick function on the button from my form targeting the name of the iframe.

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" src=""></iframe>

<button onclick="this.form.target='my_iframe'">My Button</button>
```